# Javascript - Finding previous DOM element by element type or class name

Tags: javascript, html

**Please Note: I am looking for a Javascript only solution, jQuery will not help as I can't use it with the given application I am working within.**

I have the following HTML in my DOM:

```
<div class="mktoFormRow">
<div class="mktoFieldDescriptor mktoFormCol" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="mktoOffset" style="width: 10px;"></div>
    <div class="mktoFieldWrap">
        <label for="Agency__c" class="mktoLabel mktoHasWidth" style="width: 100px;">
            <div class="mktoAsterix">*</div>Agency:</label>
        <div class="mktoGutter mktoHasWidth" style="width: 10px;"></div>
        <div class="mktoLogicalField mktoCheckboxList mktoHasWidth" style="width: 150px;">
            <input name="Agency__c" id="Agency__c" type="checkbox" value="yes" class="mktoField">
            <label for="Agency__c"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="mktoClear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mktoClear"></div>
</div>
<div class="mktoClear"></div>
```

I want to use Javascript to target the first label (in this example, the one with `for="Agency__c"`) whenever the `div` with a class of `mktoCheckboxList` is present.

This is as far as I've been able to figure out in Javascript, but I'm at a loss. My thought process is to target the previous element before `mktoCheckboxList` by either by element type of `label` or its class of `mktoLabel`.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('mktoCheckboxList');
var count = checkboxes.length;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    console.log(checkboxes[i].previousElementSibling);
}
```

This solution needs to be agnostic of an actual name value, as I want this to work whenever a checkbox is presented without knowing what it's properties are, hence the use of the class / elements.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/1y9s00k7/

Comment: Note that `Agency__c` has two labels. One of them is empty, that is at least a little bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('mktoCheckboxList');
var count = checkboxes.length;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    console.log(checkboxes[i].parentNode.querySelector('label'));
}
```

Please note that this solution will work only if you have a single `.mktoCheckboxList` element in the same div with the label.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y9s00k7/3/)

Comment: You can use querySelector('selector') instead of querySelectorAll('selector:first-child')

Answer (score 3):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is now supported by all major browsers ([see can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector)).

```
document.querySelector(".mktoCheckboxList label")
```

will select the first label it finds inside `.mktoFieldDescriptor`.

You can also do it on an element:

```
parent.querySelector("label");
```

If you need to check if a div contains a specific element before retrieving another you can do:

```
querySelectorAll(".mktoFieldDescriptor").filter(function(container){
   // Remove the containers that do not contain .mktoCheckboxList.
   return !!container.querySelector(".mktoCheckboxList");
}).map(function(container){
   // Get the first label.
   return container.querySelector("label")
}).forEach(function(label){
   // Do your label stuff.
});
```

Comment: Very close to a working solution, but I had to add the .parentNode to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach:

Bind every input with it's label. Then lookup the input you need to work with, and get the label elem by that:

```
// Scan the page for labels:
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
// Find the corresponding input:
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].htmlFor != '') {
         // Assign a reference to the label from the actual form element:
         var elem = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor);
         if (elem)
            elem.label = labels[i];         
    }
}
```

After that's done, you can easily do:

```
// Lookup all inputs:
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = inputs.length; i < max; i++){
    // Act only on checkboxes:
    if (inputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
        console.log(inputs[i]); // Look! It's the label!
}
```

Using this method you use nothing but the tag name `input` and type `checkbox` in order to locate your labels.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.evaluate` and address the label you want via XPath. Untested:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'mktoCheckboxList')]/preceding::label[1]
```